# Mapbox Driving Direction with Custom Marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I have the following code to use mapbox as my driving direction, but unfortunately it doesn't allow me to change the markers, and it keeps using its default marker even though I try to change it with geoJson

```
<script>

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyc2hpZGFsYXZpIiwiYSI6ImNpZjNmNTRrYzQ0b2xzNWx1bXN5MnlmdjUifQ.IvZZfdiPe4rxQNolE88fhg';

var __journey = {"logbook":"29","consumer":"732","account":"1","category":"13","source":"2","platform":"4","vehicle":"25","label":"Farshid","startingodometer":"20000","endingodometer":"22721","note":"","status":"unverified","isreimbursable":"no","isdeductible":"yes","type":"deductible","updated":"2015-11-25 03:42:21","created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","dbupdate":"2015-11-25 14:42:21","detail":{"logbook":"29","consumer":"732","account":"1","category":"13","source":"2","platform":"4","vehicle":"25","label":"Farshid","startingodometer":"20000","endingodometer":"22721","note":"","status":"unverified","isreimbursable":"no","isdeductible":"yes","type":"deductible","updated":"2015-11-25 03:42:21","created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","dbupdate":"2015-11-25 14:42:21"},"__consumer":{"customer":null,"customerkey":"ed64e42a-e7c1-49b9-9fef-f5dd96bcd783","firstname":null,"lastname":null,"apikey":null,"email":"farshid@ichit.com","birth":null,"pincode":null,"pinlastupdate":null,"password":null,"gender":null,"emailverify":"1","postcode":null,"reference":null,"country":null,"forgetpasswordtoken":null,"forgetpasswordexpiry":null,"ipaddress":null,"company":"3","created":null,"updated":null,"active":"1","active !=":null,"archive":"0","archive !=":null,"mobile":null},"__account":{"id":"29","account":"Business","sequence":null,"icon":null,"parent":null,"customer":null,"admin":null,"created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","updated":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","active":null},"__category":{"id":"29","category":"Home","brands":null,"keywords":null,"icon":null,"parent":null,"customer":null,"admin":null,"active":null,"customisable":null,"created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","updated":"2015-11-25 03:42:21"},"__source":{"source":"29","creator":null,"name":"My Car","updated":"2015-11-25 03:42:21","created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21"},"__platform":{"platform":"29","creator":null,"name":"My Car","updated":"2015-11-25 03:42:21","created":"2015-11-23 03:10:21"},"__route":[{"logbookroute":"1448421928.896","logbook":"29","latitude":"-37.8437403","longitude":"144.9758769","pindate":"2015-11-05","pintime":"02:09 AM","journey":"29","pinned":"2015-11-05 02:09:00"},{"logbookroute":"1448421928.901","logbook":"29","latitude":"-31.980216","longitude":"115.869578","pindate":"2015-11-22","pintime":"12:10 PM","journey":"29","pinned":"2015-11-22 12:10:00"}],"__vehicle":{"vehicle":"25","consumer":"732","name":"My Car","make":"Toyota","family":"Yaris","description":"1.4 Manual","year":"2015","odometer":"20725","registrationnumber":"123ABC","isactive":"yes","isdefualt":"no","isdeleted":"no","updated":"2015-10-10 10:10:10","created":"2015-10-10 10:10:10","dbupdate":"2015-11-23 03:10:21","log":"2","__make":false,"__family":false,"__description":false},"__reimbursement":false,"taxdeduction_code":"D5","mileage":"2721","name":"My Car","accountname":"Business","categoryname":"Home","reimbursement_status":null};
var start = {lat: '-37.8437403', lng: '144.9758769'};
var finish = {lat: '-31.980216', lng: '115.869578'};
var zoom = 9;

if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 10000) zoom = 1;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 4000) zoom = 2;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 700) zoom = 3;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 500) zoom = 5;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 400) zoom = 6;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 300) zoom = 7;
else if(Number(__journey.mileage) >= 200) zoom = 8;
else zoom = 9;

console.log(zoom);

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {zoomControl: true}).setView([-35.792529592717, 129.89108613555], zoom);

var geoJson = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
        {
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
                "marker-color": "#f76565",
                route: {id: 1, type: "origin", points: 2}
            },
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: ['144.9758769', '-37.8437403']}
        },{
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
                "marker-color": "#f76565",
                route: {id: 2, type: "destination", points: 3}
            },
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: ['115.869578', '-31.980216']
            }
        }
    ]
};

var origin = {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[144.9758769,-37.8437403]},"properties":{"marker-symbol":"circle-stroked","marker-color":"ff1f20","marker-size":"medium"}};
var destination = {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[115.869578,-31.980216]},"properties":{"marker-symbol":"circle-stroked","marker-color":"23be20","marker-size":"medium"}};

// = L.mapbox.directions({profile: 'mapbox.driving'})
var directions = L.mapbox.directions();
var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map);
var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions).addTo(map);
directions.setOrigin(origin).setDestination(destination).query();

var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map);
var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions).addTo(map);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was to customise the directions.js file, unfortunately even if you post your customise marker as part of your geoJson because it is hardcoded withing directions.js it won't change it unless you download the library and customise it yourself (you can make it dynamic as you load the geoJson object or change it as hardcode as you want) in the directions.js look for the following code

```
                L.setOptions(this, options);
            this._directions = directions || new L.Directions();
            L.LayerGroup.prototype.initialize.apply(this);

            this._drag = debounce(L.bind(this._drag, this), 100);

            this.originMarker = L.marker([0, 0], {
                draggable: !this.options.readonly,
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked",
                    "marker-color": "23be20",
                    "marker-size": "medium",
                    "stroke": "#e8b920",
                    "stroke-opacity": "1.0",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "fill":"#e8b920",
                })
            }).on('drag', this._drag, this);

            this.destinationMarker = L.marker([0, 0], {
                draggable: !this.options.readonly,
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked",
                    "marker-color": "ff1f20",
                    "marker-size": "medium",
                    "stroke": "#e8b920",
                    "stroke-opacity": "1.0",
                    "stroke-width": 5,
                    "fill":"#e8b920",
                })
            }).on('drag', this._drag, this);

            this.stepMarker = L.marker([0, 0], {
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    className: 'mapbox-marker-drag-icon mapbox-marker-drag-icon-step',
                    iconSize: new L.Point(12, 12)
                })
            });

            this.dragMarker = L.marker([0, 0], {
                draggable: !this.options.readonly,
                icon: this._waypointIcon()
            });

            this.dragMarker
                .on('dragstart', this._dragStart, this)
                .on('drag', this._drag, this)
                .on('dragend', this._dragEnd, this);

            this.routeLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
                style: this.options.routeStyle
            });
            this.routeHighlightLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
                style: this.options.routeStyle
            });

            this.waypointMarkers = [];
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mapbox Directions API inserts the standard markers on top of your custom ones. You also seem to add the `directionsLayer` and `directionsRoutesControl` several times.

This should work:

```
var geoJson = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
        {
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
                "marker-color": "#f76565",
                "marker-symbol":"circle-stroked",
                "marker-color":"ff1f20",
                "marker-size": "medium",                
                route: {id: 1, type: "origin", points: 2}
            },
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: ['144.9758769', '-37.8437403']}
        },{
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
                "marker-color": "#f76565",
                "marker-symbol":"circle-stroked",
                "marker-color":"23be20",
                "marker-size":"medium",                
                route: {id: 2, type: "destination", points: 3}
            },
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: ['115.869578', '-31.980216']
            }
        }
    ]
};

var origin = geoJson.features[0];
var destination = geoJson.features[1];

var directions = L.mapbox.directions();
var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map);
var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions).addTo(map);
directions.setOrigin(origin).setDestination(destination).query();

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

Here is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pq2wv4j9/).

Comment: If I want to customise the stroke (the line), how can I change that? Where should I put my following code?    "properties":{"stroke":"#e8b920","stroke-opacity":"1.0","stroke-width":5,"fill":"#e8b920"}

Comment: Tried it - I can change the marker colours but cannot change the icon. Fiddle with updated icon URL - http://jsfiddle.net/pq2wv4j9/4/  - the icon appears grey. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to customize the default icons of origin and destination. You can push these styles [these styles](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/src/directions_style.js) to MapboxDirections.

```
const directions = new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    unit: "metric",
    profile: "mapbox/driving",
    interactive: false,
    controls: false,
    styles: **directionStyles**
});
```

btw, If you would like to add images, try to customize the style of the map in your account. Just add new images to the map, and then you can find it in the sprite, like this:

```
{
"id": "directions-origin-label",
"type": "symbol",
"source": "directions",
"layout": {
    "icon-image": "**uploading-marker**",
},
"paint": {
    "text-color": "#fff"
},
"filter": [
    "all",
    ["in", "$type", "Point"],
    ["in", "marker-symbol", "A"]
]}
```

The next one, you need to add waypoints to the direction:

```
directions.addWaypoint(index, [ln, lat]);
```

Then next layer, you need to add Marker above the direction after map is loaded (map.current.on("load", handleMapLoad);):

```
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = className;
new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(geo).addTo(map.current);
```

And bonus :) you need to add additional waypoints to the bounds after route loading:

```
directions.on("route", () => {
    const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(
        [originPoint.ln, originPoint.lat], [destinationPoint.ln, destinationPoint.lat]
    );
    for (const coord of uploadingPointsGeo) {
        bounds.extend(coord);
    }
    for (const coord of unloadingPointsGeo) {
        bounds.extend(coord);
    }

    map.current.fitBounds(bounds, {
        padding: 30
    });});
```

You are welcome to Mapbox world :)