# mapbox-gl-directions (Plugin) how to change marker A and B

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use this plugin called mapbox-gl-directions and is there any way to change markers A and B?
I don't see any documentation or tutorial on how to edit those markers pls help me if when there are thanks.

[Image of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rphdb.png)

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import MapboxDirection from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions";

import * as Styles from "./styled";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions.css";

mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX;

const Map = () => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mystyle",
      center: [121.0503, 14.5547],
      zoom: 17,
    });

    const directions = new MapboxDirection({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      unit: "metric",
      profile: "mapbox/walking",
      alternatives: true,
      geometries: false,
      controls: { instructions: true },
      flyTo: false,
    });

    

    map.addControl(directions, "top-left");
    map.scrollZoom.enable();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Styles.Mapcontainer
        ref={mapContainer}
        className="map-container"
      ></Styles.Mapcontainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69799789/1296470 it's a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter style with these settings set marker-style for origin and destination position.
[Style Parameter Mapbox Gl](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/src/directions_style.js)

```
const style = [{
'id': 'directions-route-line-alt',
  'type': 'line',
  'source': 'directions',
  'layout': {
    'line-cap': 'round',
    'line-join': 'round'
  },
  'paint': {
    'line-color': '#bbb',
    'line-width': 4
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'LineString'],
    ['in', 'route', 'alternate']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-route-line-casing',
  'type': 'line',
  'source': 'directions',
  'layout': {
    'line-cap': 'round',
    'line-join': 'round'
  },
  'paint': {
    'line-color': '#2d5f99',
    'line-width': 12
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'LineString'],
    ['in', 'route', 'selected']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-route-line',
  'type': 'line',
  'source': 'directions',
  'layout': {
    'line-cap': 'butt',
    'line-join': 'round'
  },
  'paint': {
    'line-color': {
      'property': 'congestion',
      'type': 'categorical',
      'default': '#4882c5',
      'stops': [
        ['unknown', '#4882c5'],
        ['low', '#4882c5'],
        ['moderate', '#f09a46'],
        ['heavy', '#e34341'],
        ['severe', '#8b2342']
      ]
    },
    'line-width': 7
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'LineString'],
    ['in', 'route', 'selected']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-hover-point-casing',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 8,
    'circle-color': '#fff'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'id', 'hover']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-hover-point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 6,
    'circle-color': '#3bb2d0'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'id', 'hover']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-waypoint-point-casing',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 8,
    'circle-color': '#fff'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'id', 'waypoint']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-waypoint-point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 6,
    'circle-color': '#8a8bc9'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'id', 'waypoint']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-origin-point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 18,
    'circle-color': '#3bb2d0'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'marker-symbol', 'A']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-origin-label',
  'type': 'symbol',
  'source': 'directions',
  'layout': {
    'text-field': 'A',
    'text-font': ['Open Sans Bold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
    'text-size': 12
  },
  'paint': {
    'text-color': '#fff'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'marker-symbol', 'A']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-destination-point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'directions',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 18,
    'circle-color': '#8a8bc9'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'marker-symbol', 'B']
  ]
}, {
  'id': 'directions-destination-label',
  'type': 'symbol',
  'source': 'directions',
  'layout': {
    'text-field': 'B',
    'text-font': ['Open Sans Bold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
    'text-size': 12
  },
  'paint': {
    'text-color': '#fff'
  },
  'filter': [
    'all',
    ['in', '$type', 'Point'],
    ['in', 'marker-symbol', 'B']
  ]
}];

    const directions = new MapboxDirection({
      styles: style,
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      unit: "metric",
      profile: "mapbox/walking",
      alternatives: true,
      geometries: false,
      controls: { instructions: true },
      flyTo: false,
    });
```

Comment: not working :( I try to edit it even the colors, the marker stays the same

Comment: It's 'styles', not 'style'. check the new code now, Hopefully, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have another question. How do I change this part to make a custom marker, I can only change its color and text field

Thanks :)

```js
 {
        id: "directions-origin-point",
        type: "circle",
        source: "directions",
        paint: {
          "circle-radius": 18,
          "circle-color": "#3bb2d0",
        },
        filter: ["all", ["in", "$type", "Point"], ["in", "marker-symbol", "A"]],
      },
      {
        id: "directions-origin-label",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "directions",
        layout: {
          "text-field": "A",
          "text-font": ["Open Sans Bold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
          "text-size": 12,
        },
        paint: {
          "text-color": "#fff",
        },
        filter: ["all", ["in", "$type", "Point"], ["in", "marker-symbol", "A"]],
      },
```

Comment: Requirements are unclear, post it as a new question.